# How to extract frames from an animated gif using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animated-gif

**Does anyone have a simple solution to extract frames from a gif using javascript?**

I know some online tools like [Ezgif](http://ezgif.com/) and [Gif-explode](https://www.gif-explode.com/), but I'm wondering if this is also possible using just javascript?

Comment: It's possible in PHP with Imagick.

Comment: How ? @CharlotteDunois

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.coalesceimages.php

Comment: Why was this question closed? Any of the close-voters care to comment? It's not too broad at all to answer. This is a simple, answerable question, which is of use to more than one person.

Comment: Yah i dont understant.I am just searching for simple solution if possible @Arend .

Comment: Anyway. Here's a solution that'll export gif frames using javascript and shows them as seperate frames.. If this question somehow gets reopened  I'll post it as an answer. Until that moment, here's the example. https://jsfiddle.net/7gtLtkbw/

Comment: Thats what i am looking for.Thank you a lot! @Arend

Comment: @Arend your jsfiddle was useful to me as well. I made a modification to not actually have the image in the DOM but programatically without displaying the canvas (hope I am making sense) Step through the images var img_uri= rub.get_canvas().toDataURL("image/png"); did the trick to get the image for my purposes.

Answer (score 12):

For a client-side solution I'd recommend to have a look at [libgif-js](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js).
It allows to step to a specific frame in the GIF and you could then use the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to capture a single frame by drawing the image to the canvas and then getting the Data URL.

Comment: That would be pure js. Client side means you don't need to do it on the server but can do it in the browser