# Using `jsgif` to build layers over animated GIFs

Tags: javascript, canvas, gif

I'm looking to get some help or guidance on the use of the excellent [`libgif.js` library](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js).

My objective is to take a page that has an animated gif and a png of text with transparent background, and then show the 2 images overlaid such that the resulting image can be copied to the clipboard.

- I've succeeded in [doing this with a static image as a template](https://codepen.io/narcan_1470333528/pen/QMErge)
- However, if I try this [with a gif](https://codepen.io/narcan_1470333528/pen/xLdbWo), it merges the animated gif with the text image, but freezes the gif.

I've familiarized myself with the `libgif.js` library and have [succeeded in using it to build a canvas from an animated gif and have it remain animated](https://jsfiddle.net/narcan/f0fuu0q2/).

However, the text image is not being displayed in the final canvas, and I'm a little lost as to how I might go about fixing this.

**Is it obvious to anyone why the `textImage` is being properly sized and (somewhat) apparently placed on the canvas, but not displayed in the final result?**

As a side question, does anyone know why the progress bar completes *quickly* at first and then progresses more slowly a second time?

The HTML is rather long, but the JS from the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/narcan/f0fuu0q2/) is shown below (for those not willing to click through to the link).

```
function doit() {
  var isGIF = true; // always true for now TODO: better way to test if-gif than regex for ".gif"
  var previewContainer = document.getElementById("previewContainer");
  var textImage = document.getElementById("textImage");
  var templateImage = document.getElementById("templateImage");
  var w = document.getElementById("templateImage").width;
  var h = document.getElementById("templateImage").height;

  previewContainer.removeChild(previewContainer.children[1]);

  if (isGIF) {
    var gif = new SuperGif({
      gif: templateImage,
      progressbar_height: 5,
      auto_play: true,
      loop_mode: true,
      draw_while_loading: true
    });

    gif.load();
    var canvas = gif.get_canvas();
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(textImage, 0, 0, w, h);

    previewContainer.replaceChild(canvas, previewContainer.children[0]);
  }
}
```

Note: this solution was originally based on `Arend`'s solution in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309560/how-to-extract-frames-from-an-animated-gif-using-javascript) from [this JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309560/how-to-extract-frames-from-an-animated-gif-using-javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to tweak the library in order to get access to their rendering loop (like a *frame_rendered* event).
This way, you would be able to add whatever you want over the image the library drawn at every frame.

But since I'm too lazy to dig in there, here is a workaround :

Instead of appending the canvas returned by the library in the document, you can keep it offscreen, and draw it on an other, visible, canvas.
It is on this new canvas that you will also draw your textImage, in an rAF loop.

```js
function doit() {
  var previewContainer = document.getElementById("previewContainer");
  var textImage = document.getElementById("textImage");
  var templateImage = document.getElementById("templateImage");
  var w = templateImage.width;
  var h = templateImage.height;
  previewContainer.removeChild(previewContainer.children[1]);

  var gif = new SuperGif({
    gif: templateImage,
    progressbar_height: 5,
    auto_play: true,
    loop_mode: true,
    draw_while_loading: true
  });

  gif.load();

  var gif_canvas = gif.get_canvas(); // the lib canvas
  // a copy of this canvas which will be appended to the doc
  var canvas = gif_canvas.cloneNode();
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function anim(t) { // our animation loop
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // in case of transparency ?
    context.drawImage(gif_canvas, 0, 0); // draw the gif frame
    context.drawImage(textImage, 0, 0, w, h); // then the text
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  };
  anim();

  previewContainer.replaceChild(canvas, previewContainer.children[0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js/master/libgif.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="submit" id="doit" value="Do it!" onclick="doit()" />
</div>
<div id="previewContainer">
  <img id="templateImage" src="https://i.imgur.com/chWt4Yg.gif" />
  <img id="textImage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmErq.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great start, @Kaiido, thanks! The only issue I can see with it is that when I copy the resulting image, it's not animated (freezes the animated gif part into a frame). Any thoughts about how to fix that? (I'm not sure yet why that is, just tested the solution, but haven't really wrapped my head around it yet).

Comment: @pdro I'm not sure I get what you are saying... When you copy what ? The canvas ? Like "right-click => save Image as.." ? If so, then it's the same as the one from libgif.js, it's not a gif anymore, it's a static canvas, which gets updated in a js animation loop.  You want to export the resulting as animated gif ? Then it's not part of what libgif can do. [gif.js](https://github.com/jnordberg/gif.js) could do it, but you would have to take a whole different approach I think (like here it would be really important to have control over all extracted frames 1 at a time)

Comment: Thanks, @Kaiido - that's correct, I'm trying to get it such that I can copy the resulting animated gif and paste it into an email body and have it continue to be animated. What you said about having control over the extracted frames makes sense, and I'll give that a shot when I get a chance. If you have any examples you've worked on, I wouldn't say no :-)