# How to draw a GIF on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, gif

I have a game and I need to add animations. I have GIFs that I want to draw on the canvas. How do you draw a GIF on a canvas? Is there a way to do this without getting each frame of the GIF? I have tried to just draw it as an image, but it only draws the first frame of the image.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to ask something more specific and show your attempt.

Comment: And "gif" isn't synonymous with "animation". Be clear about that if it's what you're asking for. Gif is just an image format.

Comment: The question was fair and specific. Stop gate keeping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use invisible image as the source:

```js
const image = document.getElementById('my-image');
const canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(image, 10, 10);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="240" height="240" ></canvas>
<img width="32" height="32" id="my-image" src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
```

Comment: It takes image "as is" but I suppose it will not work with animated gif. I'm checking it out...

Comment: Well, it takes the first frame, but does not support animation, as I suggested. See the exampe here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/a8u36409/

Comment: Is there any way to make a canvas draw a animated gif?

Comment: If you can split your GIF to frames, you can draw them one by one on canvas...

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309560/how-to-extract-frames-from-an-animated-gif-using-javascript

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Your jsfiddle has a bug: Since you didn't use `image.onload` the canvas will be empty. The script only works if the user reloads the page, because loading cached images is instant. So for most of the people that see your jsfiddle will think it doesn't work.